# Как сделать вложенное меню в python-telegram-bot?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, python-telegram-bot

Мне нужно написать вложенное меню для телеграм-бота. Я использую **python-telegram-bot** и в настоящее время имею следующий код. По команде **/caregories** бот получает список родительских категорий из базы данных с помощью метода **caregory_service.get_parent_categories()** и отображает их в виде кнопок меню. Я хочу добавить в бот следующий функционал: при нажатии на каждую из кнопок категорий открывается подменю со списком подкатегорий и кнопкой возврата к списку родительских категорий. Вы можете получить список подкатегорий, используя метод **caregory_service.get_subcategories()**. При нажатии на любую из подкатегорий она добавляется в список выбранных и этот список возвращается после нажатия кнопки "ОК" в главном меню. Как я могу реализовать это с помощью **python-telegram-bot**?

```
from telegram.ext import AIORateLimiter, Application, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from telegram import Update, InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from services import CategoryService

TOKEN = 'TOKEN'

async def categories_callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    keyboard = []
    category_service = CategoryService()
    categories = await category_service.get_parent_categories() # get all parent categories from database

    categories_buttons = [[InlineKeyboardButton(category.name, callback_data=str(category.id))] for category in categories]
    keyboard.extend(categories_buttons)

    keyboard.extend([
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Cancel ",
            callback_data="cancel"
        )],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Ok ",
            callback_data="confirm"
        )]])

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)

    await update.message.reply_text(
        "Some text",
        reply_markup=reply_markup
    )


def create_bot() -> Application:
    bot = Application.builder().token(TOKEN).rate_limiter(AIORateLimiter()).build()
    bot.add_handler(CommandHandler("categories", categories_callback))
    return bot


async def start_bot() -> Application:
    bot = create_bot()
    await bot.initialize()
    await bot.updater.start_polling()
    await bot.start()
    return bot

bot = start_bot()
```

Answer (score 0):

Создайте состояния для вашего чата:

```
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
from telegram.ext import ConversationHandler, CallbackQueryHandler

SELECT_PARENT_CATEGORY, SELECT_SUBCATEGORY, CONFIRM = range(3)
```

Определите функцию для команды /categories:

```
async def categories_callback(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    keyboard = []
    category_service = CategoryService()
    categories = await category_service.get_parent_categories()

    categories_buttons = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(category.name, callback_data=str(category.id))] for category in categories
    ]
    keyboard.extend(categories_buttons)

    keyboard.extend([
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Cancel ",
            callback_data="cancel"
        )],
        [InlineKeyboardButton(
            "Ok ",
            callback_data="confirm"
        )]
    ])

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    await update.message.reply_text("Choose a parent category:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return SELECT_PARENT_CATEGORY
```

Определите функцию для обработки выбора категории:

```
async def select_category(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.callback_query
    category_id = int(query.data)

    # Добавьте код для получения подкатегорий по category_id
    # ...

    # Постройте InlineKeyboardMarkup для подкатегорий
    subcategories_keyboard = [
        [InlineKeyboardButton(subcategory.name, callback_data=f"sub_{subcategory.id}")]
        for subcategory in subcategories
    ]
    subcategories_keyboard.append([InlineKeyboardButton("Back to categories", callback_data="back")])

    reply_markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(subcategories_keyboard)

    await query.edit_message_text("Choose a subcategory:", reply_markup=reply_markup)

    return SELECT_SUBCATEGORY
```

Определите функцию для обработки выбора подкатегории:

```
async def select_subcategory(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    query = update.callback_query
    subcategory_id = int(query.data.split("_")[1])

    # Добавьте код для обработки выбора подкатегории, например, добавьте ее в список выбранных
    # ...

    await query.answer("Subcategory selected!")

    return SELECT_PARENT_CATEGORY  # Вернуться к выбору родительской категории
```

Определите функцию для обработки подтверждения:

```
async def confirm(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    # Добавьте код для обработки выбранных категорий и выполнения необходимых действий
    # ...

    await update.message.reply_text("Confirmed!")

    return ConversationHandler.END
```

Определите функцию для обработки отмены:

```
async def cancel(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await update.message.reply_text("Cancelled!")

    return ConversationHandler.END
```

Добавьте обработчики в приложение:conversation_handler = ConversationHandler(

```
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('categories', categories_callback)],
    states={
        SELECT_PARENT_CATEGORY: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_category)],
        SELECT_SUBCATEGORY: [CallbackQueryHandler(select_subcategory)],
        CONFIRM: [CallbackQueryHandler(confirm)],
    },
    fallbacks=[CallbackQueryHandler(cancel)],
)

bot.add_handler(conversation_handler)
```